# flow control - automate the boring stuff (is it raining)

Tags: python, control-flow

I have looked at this so many times and confused myself.

Looking at the flow chart:

[image: flow]

I am getting confused on how to do the loop on the right hand side. This how I "think" it looks.

- Is it raining? (Y) - Have umbrella? (Y) - Go outside.
- Is it raining? (Y) - Have umbrella? (N) - wait a while ... is it raining (Y) ... wait a while ... is it raining etc etc
- Is it raining? (Y) - Have umbrella? (N) - wait a while ... is it raining (N) - Go outside
- Is it raining (N) - Go outside.

This is how I have implemented so far...but after wait a while...and yes to raining, my code goes back to asks me if I have an umbrella.

Where am I going wrong?

```py
import time


while True:

    r = input("is it raining? y/n: ")

    if r == "y":
        u = input("do you have an umbrella? y/n: ")

        if u == "y":
            print("Go Outside")
            break

        if u == "n":
            print("wait a while")
            time.sleep(3)
            r = True
    else:
        print("Go Outside")
        break
```

Comment: Note: the "Is raining?" block on the _left_ isn't part of a loop, but the _rightmost_ "Is raining?" block is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for a global loop, the question "Have umbrella?", for example, is only asked once. The following code should do the trick:

```
import time

r = input("is it raining? y/n: ")
if r == "y":
    u = input("do you have an umbrella? y/n: ")
    if u == "n":
        while r == "y":
            print("wait a while")
            time.sleep(3)
            r = input("is it raining? y/n: ")
print("Go Outside")
```

Comment: Thanks man! That has fixed it...Looking at the flow statement again with your answer has made me see where I have gone wrong.